# Discretization by only one column of the dataset using mdlp()

Tags: r

library(discretization)
data("CO2")
disc<- mdlp(CO2[4])

I just need to discretize the 4th column of the data set provided. Then it is getting an `Error in data[1, ] : incorrect number of dimensions` error. Could you please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're going for, but 1) mdlp needs more than just one column of data, and 2) it also has trouble working with complex objects like CO2. Here is one way to make it execute:

```
CO2.df <- as.data.frame(CO2) # strips the extra info
mdlp(CO2.df[,4:5])
```

Comment: Thank you. I just need to know that whether mdlp can discretize just one column. Thank you for that.